# Moq - Ordered Setups (Expectations)

Tags: .net, unit-testing, moq

I am fairly new to Moq and cant work out how I am to order setups. I have the following code:

```
_orderRepository.Setup(r => r.Update(It.Is<Order>(a => ((int)a.OrderStatusReference.EntityKey.EntityKeyValues[0].Value) == 2)))
                        .Throws(exception)
                        .AtMost(5);
```

I want this to be executed 5 times (its retry logic, if the update fails).  After the 5th time I want to setup and expect that it is successful (An exception is not thrown):

```
_orderRepository.Setup(r => r.Update(It.Is<Order>(a => ((int)a.OrderStatusReference.EntityKey.EntityKeyValues[0].Value) == 2))).AtMostOnce();
```

Unfortinatly it continues to use the 1st code sample, and never successfully updates.

If I were not using the Throws method, then I can use the Callback method, however its not available after a throw :(.

If there a way or is this a limitation of Moq?

Comment: What version of Moq are you using? My version doesn't allow me to specify AtMost(5) and AtMostOnce() after a Setup()...

Comment: Version 3.1.0.0, Its weird it doesnt let you specify them, how would you expect it to be only called x number of times!?  Perhaps an older version uses a different method?

Comment: Okay, I digged a little more into this. It turns out that AtMost and AtMostOnce are hidden as described here: http://www.clariusconsulting.net/blogs/kzu/archive/2009/01/08/115183.aspx That strongly suggests to me that this way of defining how many times a method was invoked is on the way out. I may be wrong, but the Verify method provides an IntelliSense-visible alternative.

Comment: "AtMost and AtMostOnce are hidden".. hidden from intellisense?  It is not hidden for me!  What version are you using?

I hope it doesnt go... the Verify method requires extra lines of code and makes the tests untidy and harder to read.  I could always add an extension to maintain the AtMostOnce...

Thanks for the research.

Comment: For the record I'm using version 3.1.something - can't remember the exact version, but it was a bit higher than 3.1.0.0...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moq doesn't support ordering of expectations. See [here](http://groups.google.com/group/moqdisc/browse_thread/thread/80404b259824812d?pli=1) for more details.

Although I currently use Moq, I used to use RhinoMocks before, and it certainly has some features that I occasionally miss with Moq - ordered expectations being one of them.

Comment: I did read that article before posting here, however I was hoping a year later they saw sense and provided us with that feature!  Hmm going to have to try and roll my own "ordering mechanism" if I have time..  Next project will use RhinoMocks if I have my way! :)... thanks.

Answer (score 16):

Bah... there are ways!

You can use a Queue to return a list of return values (strategy explained pretty well here: http://haacked.com/archive/2009/09/29/moq-sequences.aspx).

Here's a sample from that blog:

If you want this to work (which it doesn't):

```
reader.Setup(r => r.Read()).Returns(true);
reader.Setup(r => r.Read()).Returns(true);
reader.Setup(r => r.Read()).Returns(false);
```

Just do this instead:

```
Queue listOfOperations = new Queue<bool>(new bool[] { true, true, false });

reader.Setup(r => r.Read())
  .Returns(() => listOfOperations.Dequeue());
```

Each time Read() is called a new value from your Queue will be used.

Enjoy!

Comment: Thats fine, you can do the same using callbacks.  The question refers to doing that with regards to Throw.  I need it to throw x times then return.

Comment: You are right... I missed that.  Sorry for the confusion.  I'll leave this here because it's a good pattern for returns, but the throws situation is still not really supported here, unless you can throw from a Returns.

Comment: Just a heads up but that last piece of code is incorrect. That will always return true.  The queue creation needs to go outside the setup

Comment: You are right... I wrote a similar closure bug just recently.  I've learned my lesson :)

Comment: .Returns(listOfOperations.Dequeue()) should be .Returns(() => listOfOperations.Dequeue()) or .Returns(listOfOperations.Dequeue) (with missing parenthesis). Otherwise you bind the return value of .Read() to the value returned by listOfOperations.Dequeue() at the time of binding which will result in it returning true every time, independently of how many times you call it

Comment: @Simen Echholt: You are right. That's what I get for programming right in the comments box rather than testing.

Answer (score 3):

I also needed the same thing and ended up with writing this extension method, which works for me:

```
public static class MoqExtensions {
    public static void Returns<TMock,TResult>(this ISetup<TMock, TResult> source, params TResult[] results) where TMock : class {
        int currentResultIndex = 0;

        source.Returns (() => {
            if(currentResultIndex >= results.Length) {
                currentResultIndex = 0;
            }

            return results [currentResultIndex++];
        });
    }
}
```

And sample usage is:

```
someMock.Setup(o => o.AMethodWithReturnTypeInt()).Returns(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

For this sample, if you call the stubbed method -let's say- 6 times, it will return 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2 respectively.

Hope this helps...